# Recent Pushed Commit info on Files and Merge/Pull Request in Gitlab and Github

Tags: git, github, gitlab, merge-request

I see an info message on the Files and Merge Request that I made recently pushed commits with an option to create a merge request with the main branch. I'm just curious how it helps other developers who create merge requests with protected branches instead of the main branch.

Comment: Your question is not clear, what do you want to know exactly?

Comment: I don't see that it does help for that. The only thing it would seem to help is to allow people to figure out which commits and/or names were pushed recently.